# Why is T one-to-one iff T is onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In Friedberg's *Linear Algebra*, the following proof that T is one-to-one if and only if T is onto is presented. Here, $T:V\rightarrow F$ is linear.

"We have that T is one-to-one if and only if N(T)=0, if and only if nullity(T) = 0, if and only if rank(T) = dim(V), if and only if rank(T) = dim(W), and if and only if dim(R(T))=dim(W)."

My questions is how does it follow that rank(T) = dim(W) from knowing that rank(T) = dim(V)?

Comment: What is $W$?  In your first line, you wrote $V\to F$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This holds only if V and W have equal (finite) dimensions.

From the rank-nullity theorem one has:

$nullity(T)+rank(T) = dim(V)$

Since $T$ is injective then $nullity (T)=0$. Then this implies $rank (T)=dim (V)=dim (W) $ which suggests surjectivity.